# Build list of data validation attributes for a given element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, unobtrusive-validation

When using any of the [Input Extension Helper Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions), like [`@Html.TextboxFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor), any [Validation Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute) from your model are automatically generated by the Razor engine (via [`ClientValidationEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext.clientvalidationenabled)/[`UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewcontext.unobtrusivejavascriptenabled)).

For example, take the following case which works fine

**Model**:

```cs
[Required]
public string QuestionOne { get; set; }
```

**View**:

```cs
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.QuestionOne) 
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionOne)
```

**Generated Markup**:

```html
<input type="text" id="QuestionOne" name="QuestionOne" value=""
       data-val="true" data-val-required="The QuestionOne field is required." > 
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="QuestionOne" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

In this case the attributes `data-val="true"` & `data-val-required="The QuestionOne field is required."` are picked up by Unobtrusive validation and the form element is successfully validated.

---

**However**, for extensibility reasons, I want to be able to generate the `<input>` element myself instead of using `TextBoxFor`.  So my view would now look like this:

```html
<input type="textbox" 
       id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.QuestionTwo)"
       name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.QuestionTwo)" 
       value="@Model.QuestionTwo"
       data-val="true" data-val-required="Selection is Required" />

@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.QuestionTwo)
```

In this case, I'm faking the validation attribute output by just re-writing `data-val="true" (etc)` by hand, but this would have to be expanded to cover every single case.

#### [Here's a running Demo in .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4U6pIO)

**Q: Can I build /return a list of `data-val-*` attributes for a given element?**

Comment: The `HtmlHelper` has a `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` method that returns the `data-*` attributes (but you need to get the `ModelMetaData` from the expression). All you have shown is the exact same html that will be generated by the `TextBoxFor()` method except for the `value` attribute if the property is invalid (because your no longer binding correctly). What are you wanting to achieve with this?

Comment: My uses are a little more varied.  I'd like to find a way to add validation to [this custom `<select>` element](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27725829/1366033) and to [this `<input typed="checked">`](http://benfoster.io/blog/checkbox-lists-in-aspnet-mvc) element.

Comment: I know the first is yours, but that is an ugly  solution.The way to handle creating custom html in cases like that is to create you own extension method where you have access to the `ModelMetadata` and `HtmlHelper` methods, and have complete control over your html (and in that example, the view code would be (say) `@Html.GeoDropdownListFor(m=> m.CityId, Model.Cities);`

Comment: @Stephen I'm having similar stumbles as OP. My trouble is that I don't know how to correctly implement my own HTML helper. All I have to work with is the source code, which is an absolute nightmare saturated in so many callbacks I have the hardest time finding the actual logic.

Comment: Did you not try the `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` method? Or are you not understanding how to use it?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks again, I missed that originally.  It looks like it'll do exactly what I need. I'm fiddling around with it as per [How to use Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8239929/1366033), but having trouble with the implementation in my case, but that's likely a new question by the time I can document how/why it's returning empty

Comment: I'll update the fiddle for you in an hour or 2 to show you how to implement it. But its still really unclear why you would want to do this

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Something wonky is happening with `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes`, in that the first time I call the method I'll get real results, but [immediately refreshing it turns up nothing](https://i.imgur.com/OPSrYxn.png), which I suspect is creating a problem when calling it from inside an EditorTemplate.  I'll write up separately what in the world I'm trying to do; just been trying to keep questions on topic and narrow in scope.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, The refresh conundrum is in the docs [`On the first call, a collection of attributes is returned. Further calls (on the same field) return an empty collection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.getunobtrusivevalidationattributes.aspx) -  I wonder if that's what's clearing the collection when I try to use `Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(Html.NameFor(model => model).ToString())` inside of an `EditorFor()` if during the route there, it has already called that method behind the scenes

Comment: No, you misunderstanding that comment - if you have 2 inputs for the same property name, the `data-val-*` attributes will not be added for the 2nd one (I'll find a link for you shortly to explain). Just refreshing the page will not result in the attributes 'disappearing'. If they are its something else in your code causing the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160549/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kylemit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes()` method of `HtmlHelper` to get the validation attributes associated with a specific property.

For example in the view

```
@{ var attributes = Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes("QuestionTwo"); }

<input 
    type="textbox"
    @foreach(var attr in attributes)
    {
        @:@attr.Key="@attr.Value"
    }
    id="@Html.IdFor(m => m.QuestionTwo)"
    ....
/>
```

Note the `@:@attr.Key="@attr.Value"` line will give a warning (*Missing attribute name*) but will run correctly

Alternatively, you could use javaScript/jQuery to add the attributes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var attributes = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(attributes));
    var input = $('#QuestionTwo');
    for(var i in attributes) {
        input.attr(i, attributes[i]);
    }
</script>
```

I have forked the [DotNetFiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e2WnPl) to show the working code for both options.

While the above code shows how it can be done, you should not be doing that. The `HtmlHelper` methods execute a lot of code your ignoring to ensure correct 2-way model binding, for example, the `value` attribute is determined by first checking for a value in `ModelState`, then in the `ViewDataDictionary`, and only if the previous values do not exist, does it use the value of the property (the second part of [TextBoxFor displaying initial value, not the value updated from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) explains the behavior).

Except for the incorrect `value` attribute, the code you have shown for the `<input>` is the same as will be generated by simply using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Question2)`. I assume your real case is different, but if you cannot make use of `TextBoxFor()` and using an overload that accepts `htmlAttributes` to generate the html you need, then the correct approach is to create your own `HtmlHelper` method (and making use of existing methods in the `HtmlHelper` class and `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace)